# API to manipulate photo overlays

Tags: objective-c, ios, ipad, api, image-processing

I'm making an iPad app and I have this image: [image: EGG!] I'd like offer users the option to replace the egg's face with a photo from their own library (assuming I have an egg with a blank space for the head). I was wondering if there was a suitable api for manipulating/overlaying photos or images I can plug in? Any advice much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to look at the CoreImage libraries if you want to do basic image manipulations as you're describing.

First you'll get an image from the users library - you'll present a UIImagePicker modally (in the simplest scenario). This will give you back the selected image.

You'll then proceed to identify a face - CoreImage gives you a CIDetector, and this can be used to obtain a rect containing the face. You'll then grab an image, presumably, from just the rectangle around the face.

Then you take the face image, and place it behind your masked egg.